# swift navigation bar error with side menu

Tags: ios, swift, navigationbar

I'm making sidebar menu with the tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/78568/create-slide-out-navigation-panel-swift

[Before/After calling menu (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mihf2.png)

When the sidemenu is not visible navigation bar, It looks fine. But when with side menu, the bar gets error...

Everything works fine other than this.

Any idea why this happens & how to fix this? Or this is just simulator problem...? I haven't run this on real iPhone.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you post some code ? and where it gives error ?

Comment: @sourav I'm doing basically the same as tutorial, and the image with link (I can't post image yet!) shows what the error is

Comment: i have also tried the same tutorial before and it works fine . we can  help only if you mention what you are getting error .

Comment: Did you see the image? That's what my error is, the navigation bar gets weird when I open side menu. Functionally my app does all things exactly what I want.

Comment: Actually this is bug in the simulator . not in code . Try cleaning all the derived data and delete the app and run again .

Comment: I thought so! Thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this is bug in the simulator . not in code . Try cleaning all the derived data and delete the app and run again . – @sourav

@Sourav gave an answer with comment. Thanks a lot!